# Slide the Owl Carousel Controls

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, owl-carousel

I am using owl carousel slider in my site.

In the slider have more controls (see the image selected in black color).

[image]

> CODE :

```js
$("#owl-demo-2").owlCarousel({
  navigation : false,
  slideSpeed : 300,
  paginationSpeed : 400,
  singleItem : true,
  pagination : true,
  items : 1,
  afterMove:function(){
    var length = this.owl.owlItems.length;
    var current_item = this.owl.currentItem;
    /*- need to work here -*/
  },
  afterInit:function(){
    var length = this.owl.owlItems.length;
    var current_item = this.owl.currentItem;
    for(var i = 5; i < length; i++ ) {
      $("#owl-demo-2 .owl-controls .owl-pagination .owl-page:eq("+ i +")").css('display', 'none');
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="owl-demo-2" class="owl-carousel">
  <div class="item"><img src="img/product-img-1.jpg"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="img/product-img-1.jpg"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="img/product-img-1.jpg"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="img/product-img-1.jpg"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="img/product-img-1.jpg"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="img/product-img-1.jpg"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="img/product-img-1.jpg"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="img/product-img-1.jpg"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="img/product-img-1.jpg"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="img/product-img-1.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

I need to show only 5 controls in the slider (include active slider) and the another controls need to show the slider format.

How I achieve this, help me.

Thanks

Comment: `show the slider format` ?? i am not sure what you mean by this.

Comment: 5 circle Image(controls) only need to show in that area. 
4 controls in-active (white color), 1 controls active(black color).

Comment: I drag that controls, then will show the next controls.

Comment: I understand what you want now: you want all bullets to be present in the page, but the pagination div to have limited width, with hidden overflow and you want the pagination to be scrollable (or swipeable) horizontally. You should really find another solution. This is wrong as user-experience, it will be hard to make it work cross-browser/cross-platforms/cross-device and besides, you want a swipe over swipe effect (owl carousel slides are swipe-able, right?). Not friendly.

Comment: Yes,  @AndreiGheorghiu this I want exactly.
Give me any other suggestion how achieve this ..?

Comment: I cannot help you based on a picture. You need to provide an appropriate code snippet and I will modify it.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu I have added myself trying code. please check the updated answer.

Comment: Yeah, just use previous/next controls and skip the bullets. Simple is best in most cases. What you're describing would be very frustrating.

Comment: I agree with @isherwood, previous/next buttons would be better.

Comment: @isherwood Already I have asked my client But they preferred this bullet type.

Comment: Do they know what you're planning to do with the bullets? Sometimes clients need you to point out the obvious.

Comment: I guess you want something like: Show only the first 5 pagination circles and the user gets to the next 5 images it should start from the beginning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Below Code :-

```
        afterMove:function(elem){
            var length = len = this.owl.owlItems.length;
            var current_owl_id = "owl-demo";
            if(length > 5) {
                var current_item_position = this.owl.currentItem;
                var current_item = 1 + current_item_position;
                var slide_row = Math.ceil(current_item/4);
                var slide_row_start = ((slide_row * 4) - 4);
                if( slide_row_start == current_item_position) {
                    var before_position = current_item_position - 1;
                    var val = check_before_postion_css(current_owl_id, before_position);
                    if( val == "none") {
                        slide_row = slide_row - 1;
                    }
                }
                var slide_row_start = ((slide_row * 4) - 4);
                if( current_item != length) {
                    slide_row_start = (slide_row_start <= 0) ? 0 :slide_row_start;
                    scroll_slide(current_owl_id, slide_row_start, 5, length, current_item);
                }
            }

        }
```

Also add these functions in top and change the id name:

```
 function scroll_slide(id, start, end, length, current_item) {
    $("#"+id +" .owl-controls .owl-pagination .owl-page").css('display', 'none');
    if(start > 0) {
        start = parseInt(current_item / 4) * 4;
    }
    start = (start -  parseInt(current_item / 4));
    start = (start <= 0) ? 0 : start;
    for(var i = 0; i < end; i++ ) {
        $("#"+id +" .owl-controls .owl-pagination .owl-page:eq("+ start +")").css('display', 'inline-block');
        start++;
    }
}
function check_before_postion_css(id, position) {
    return $("#"+id +" .owl-controls .owl-pagination .owl-page:eq("+ position +")").css('display');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working jsfiddle using the latest version of Owl with what you want/need.

http://jsfiddle.net/zu1hvhua/3/

With this CSS I am centering the controls and hiding the overflow:

```
.owl-controls {
    width: 130px;
    height: 28px;
    overflow: hidden;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 4px solid black;
}
.owl-dots {
    height: 28px;
    width: 100vw;
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    transition: left .3s ease;
}
.owl-dots .owl-dot {
    float: left;
}
```

And this JS changes the left margin of the dots, so the active one is always in view. Looks more complicated that it is, I had to handle the exceptions (towards the ends).

```
var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
owl.owlCarousel({
    margin: 10,
    loop: true
});
owl.on('changed.owl.carousel', function(event) {
    var activeIndex =  $('.owl-dots>.active').index(), dots = $('.owl-dots .owl-dot');
    if (activeIndex > 2) {
        if (activeIndex < (dots.length - 2)) {
            left = '-' + (24 * (activeIndex -2 )) + 'px';
        } else {
            left = '-' + (24 * (dots.length - 5 )) + 'px';
        }
    } else {
        left = '0';
    }
    $('.owl-dots').css({'left': left});
});
```

The principle behind the code is quite simple: I setup the `.owl-controls` as a small viewing window with `overflow: hidden;`.

Behind it, I let the `.owl-dots` have 100% of device screen width. On changing the slide, I change the dots container's position using `left`, to make sure the active dot is always in the middle, except when we're at the first or last 2 slides.

Comment: While technically impressive, this is guaranteed to be confusing and frustrating for the user.

Comment: @iserwood: You're probably right. Sometimes a simple concept ends up in more complex code due to exceptions that need to be handled. What other options are there? fiddle updated, code a bit cleaner now